# What was the deal with Frasier and Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, frasier

The long-running sitcom *Frasier* (1993-2004) made frequent references to the Star Trek franchise.  These include:

- The character of Noel Shempsky is an avid Trekkie, much to the chagrin of everyone around him.
- In revenge for Frasier failing to obtain *Enterprise* actor Scott Bakula's autograph at a sci-fi convention, Noel translates Frasier's speech for his son's Bar Mitzvah into Klingon instead of Hebrew, causing Frasier much embarrassment.
- A number of Star Trek actors guest starred on *Frasier*, most notably Brent Spiner and Patrick Stewart.

[image][image]

- Kelsey Grammer himself made a guest appearance on *TNG* as Captain Morgan Bateman in "Cause and Effect" (although that was during his run playing Frasier on *Cheers*).

Is this simply because *Frasier* was, like the various Star Trek properties, produced by Paramount?  Did Paramount want to use *Frasier* as a vehicle to push its various Star Trek productions at the time?  Was it just a random effect of filming on adjacent lots?  Was it that a *Frasier* writer was a big fan of Star Trek?

**What was the reason for the many Star Trek references in *Frasier*?**

Comment: and don't forget this gold: (the cast of Fraiser on Voyager)
 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAVFOVgwBrY

Comment: @NKCampbell LOL! That's not just gold, it's goldpressed latinum. :D

Comment: I had this conversation with a co-worker recently, and am just now watching a Frazier episode starring Robert Picardo...

Comment: Kelsey Grammer guest-starred on TNG; https://img.comc.com/i/Non-Sports/1996/SkyBox-30-Years-of-Star-Trek-Phase-3---Base/272/Celebrity-Tributes---Kelsey-Grammer-as-Captain-Morgan-Bateman.jpg?id=f037bcc8-f7ec-4dff-b4b7-e821af6a0cab&size=zoom&side=back

Comment: **"AVC:** *Did they just call you up and ask if you’d be interested in doing a cameo?* **KG:** *Well, Jonathan Frakes is kind of a buddy of mine, and he just called up and said, “Hey, what are you doing? Can you come over for a day and shoot a scene as this guy?” And I said, “I’d love to, sure.”* - https://tv.avclub.com/kelsey-grammer-on-boss-frasier-and-toy-story-2-s-rep-1798232987

Comment: It's almost certainly down to the fact that the two shows shared studio space. Frasier was filmed on [Paramount Stage 25](http://www.thestudiotour.com/productions.php?id=11). TNG and Voyager were [filmed less than a hundred yards away](http://www.totaltrans.com/cinegear/Parking2012.jpg). The closest eatery is between the two so it's highly likely the actors and producers would meet on a daily basis

Comment: Kelsey Grammer was in Frasier with Jane Leeves, Jane Leeves was in the US Red Dwarf pilot which was produced by Linwood Boomer, who also produced Malcolm in the Middle which had Bryan Crantson, who was in Breaking Bad with John de Lancie, who was in Star Trek TNG (mainly) as Q...

Comment: @colmde And John de Lancie was in "Multiplicity" with Andie MacDowell who was in "Beauty Shop" starring Kevin Bacon. Done!

Comment: Another thing, a beloved DS9 character is based off of a character from Cheers

Comment: Don't forget DS9's regular guest in Quark's bar, *Morn*, who is a reference to Cheers' regular guest *Norm*

Comment: What is the _deal_ with all these 90s references?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best explanation is that the two series were being produced by the same company (Paramount), in the same location (on the studio lot) and that there was some overlap in the end of TNG (1987-1994) and the start of Frasier (1993-2004), as well as the subsequent TNG movies.

[As noted by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frasier)

> As with Cheers, most episodes were filmed on Stage 25, Paramount Studios, or at various locations in and around Los Angeles.

And [all Star Trek TV series have been filmed in some fashion at Paramount Studios](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Filming_locations), going all the way back to TOS.

Another reason is that Hollywood is a small town, and guest starring is a good way to keep up relations and your portfolio. TNG, in particular, [had a long list of people who guest starred before they were popular](http://www.warpedfactor.com/2014/11/25-famous-people-who-guest-starred-on.html). It's worth noting that [Cause and Effect](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode)) was produced in 1992, before Grammer had become the major solo star that the *Frasier* TV series made him. He got the TNG role as [a result of Jonathan Frakes (Riker), a personal friend](https://tv.avclub.com/kelsey-grammer-on-boss-frasier-and-toy-story-2-s-rep-1798232987) (h/t Valorum)

As to Stewart and Spiner showing up in *Frasier*, both were in episodes aired in 2003. [Star Trek: Nemesis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0253754/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_37) was filmed at Paramount in 2002, when those episodes were produced.

Comment: I like this, but readers might misinterpret one of your sentences, which could be interpreted as saying that Grammer wasn't playing Frasier at the time of "Cause and Effect".  In fact, he was, as Frasier Crane was his character on *Cheers* (and *Frasier* was a spin-off of *Cheers*).

Comment: @Praxis I forgot it was a spinoff (it's been a while). Edited

Comment: https://tv.avclub.com/kelsey-grammer-on-boss-frasier-and-toy-story-2-s-rep-1798232987 - This interview indicates that Grammer's cameo on Star Trek was at the instigation of Jonathan Frakes, a personal friend.